# How does Fortran handle augmented assignment of arrays?

Tags: arrays, fortran, variable-assignment, in-place, augmented-assignment

I've been working on some code lately that requires me to shift elements in an array left, right, up, and down (depending on an index `i`). My first thought was to try something like this:

```
subroutine shift(f)
    real, intent(inout) :: f(0:8, rDim, cDim)
    real :: periodicHor(rDim)

    periodicHor(:) = f(1,:,cDim)
    f(1,:,2:cDim)  = f(1,:,1:cDim - 1)
    f(1,:,1)       = periodicHor(:)

    !and so on for directions 2:8
end subroutine
```

However, when I lay it out this way, column 1 gets copied into column 2, which gets copied into column 3 which gets copied into... It's not a shift of the data so much as the first column overwriting everything to the left.

If I flip the indices, though,

```
subroutine betterShift(f)
    real, intent(inout) :: f(rDim, cDim, 0:8)
    real :: periodicHor(rDim)

    periodicHor(:) = f(:,cDim,1)
    f(:,2:cDim,1)  = f(:,1:cDim - 1,1)
    f(:,1,1)       = periodicHor(:)
end subroutine
```

things work fine, shifting left or right. I suspect the compiler detects an in-place update of continuous memory in the 2nd case, so it makes a temporary copy "under the hood" to avoid the overwrite issue, but that's just speculation on my part. Can anyone give a more detailed explanation as to why the shift works one way and not the other?

Comment: It's too late here to figure things out for you.  Is there a reason you're not using the intrinsics `cshift` and `eoshift` ?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is compiling? With f intent(in) and being modified in the subroutine.

Comment: Mark: I didn't know Fortran had those! That will solve a lot of problems. I'm still curious as to why the indexing would make a difference, though.

innoSPG: Heh, good point. Should have been inout. Fixed now.

Comment: Ha ha, RTFM as we say: read the Fortran manual.